# How can I merge all dataframes in a list to a single dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a list formed of 10 dataframes named MS1, ..., MS10. Each dataframe has a column 'DateTime' which is a POSIXct and a column 'Depth' (integer value). The dataframes are all of different lengths but all have overlapping DateTimes at some point.

To make simultaneous analysis and plotting of this data easier I would like to have all of these in a single dataframe with one column for DateTime and 10 columns named MS1, ..., MS10 holding the values previously held in the 'Depth' column for each dataframe. I would like to retain all values.

I am aware that there are various functions in R for joining merging dataframes (e.g. `merge`, `rbind`, `join`) but I am unsure which method is the best to do this task?

Comment: Probable [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8091303/324364)?

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. There is no example that would allow any demonstration of methods or support any judgments about how "best to do" what is vaguely described.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- df.list[[1]]
for (i in 2:length(df.list)) {
  df <- merge(df, df.list[[i]], by = DateTime, all = TRUE)
}
```